# Why is this object undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firebug is showing an error when I execute this code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "../foos/.....",
dataType: "json",
success: function (foos, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= foos.length; i++) {
        var foo = foos[i];
        alert(foo.id);
    };
}});
```

The json returns a var "foos" with id and name properties.
even alerting the foo.id propertie, firebug shows the error:

```
alert(foo.id) //foo is undefined
```

Why is foo undefined when it is correctly displayed in the alert?

EDIT:
I assigned foo twice, sorry. But even if I don't do that, i have the same firebug error.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what will be returned by the http request?

Comment: I don't understand what your code is doing. Why are you declaring `foo` in your loop and doing nothing with it? You are also using `i` out of its loop context...

Comment: You should not defined foo twice... var foo = {} and var foo = foos[i]

Comment: @ElRonnoco No he is not. Read the code again. But he is indeed declaring and assigning a value to foo twice.

Comment: @Connel, This is an example of what will be returned: [{"id":12913,"name":"Test ECG "}]

Comment: Yeah ignore me, I'm talking rubbish!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which foo did you want? The foo from the array (foos) or the foo you re-declare within the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= foos.length; i++) {
    var foo = {
        id: "",
        name:""
    };

    var foo = foos[i];
    alert(foo.id);
 };
```

But, crucially, this isn't the problem. The problem is that you loop from `0` to `foos.length`:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= foos.length; i++)
```

Which means on the last iteration of the loop, the index `i` is 1 greater than the maximum index of the array. When you try to read this element it is, indeed, undefined.

You should change your loop to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++)
```

(and of course get rid of the redefined `foo`).

Result should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
    var foo = foos[i];
    alert(foo.id);
 };
```